# Removing from Priority Queue Java

Tags: java, priority-queue

I was wondering since the API says that the `remove()` function returns a boolean type, how do I grab the element's info when I remove it. That is, is it possible to do:

```
class Node {
  int stuff;
}

PriorityQueue <Node> nodes = new PriorityQueue <Node> ();

Node temp = nodes.remove(0);
```

Assuming off course, that the nodes PQ has a bunch of nodes in it. Would `temp` node have the information of the removed node or would that not work since `remove()` returns a boolean

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish exactly? You're probably using the wrong `Collection` for the job.

Comment: remove() returns a Node.  remove(Object o) returns a boolean.  You are using the wrong remove function.  remove(int index) is part of List, not Queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [poll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#poll%28%29) method to retrieve head element

Comment: `poll()` is no replacement for what he wants since it only returns the head. Whereas `remove(Object o)` deletes the object no matter the position in the queue.

Comment: @Psy, I understand. I just thought that there's no point to 'grab the element's info' while removing it. I think OP just want to retrieve queue's head element. Anyway, I just made a link to documentation and didn't claim that this will solve all of the problems.

Comment: @Psy yeah my bad, I am trying to get the head of the queue

Answer (score 3):

In a Queue, you can't remove Objects by position `remove(int)`, you can only remove by reference `remove(E)`. Queues aren't designed for random access. (The only exception probably being `LinkedList`, as that implements both the `List` and `Queue` interface). Your code does not compile.

Comment: but what if I know the exact position i of the element and want to remove it constant time but not in O(n)?

Comment: @mvb13 then you'll need a Queue implementation that provides random access efficiently. The jdk has no such Queue, but there are some high-performance collection libraries. Perhaps one of them has such a beast. Happy hunting!

Answer (score 0):

That wouldn't work, you'll end up with a compile error because you're trying to assign the primitive type `boolean` to a variable that contains a reference to a `Node` instance. If you can access the Nodes in your `PriorityQueue` by index, you can save a reference to the object in whichever index you want first, and then remove it.

That said, looking briefly at the API for the [`PriorityQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) class, it looks like your usage of [`remove()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) is incorrect as well (it takes an object, not an `int`).

Answer (score 0):

This is where it is best to read the documentation.  remove(object) removes that object from the queue.  Due to backward compatibility its not smart enough to tell you there is no Integers in your queue. i.e. you are trying to remove the object `(Integer) 0`

Instead you should use the remove() method which takes no arguments which

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue. This method differs from poll only in that it throws an exception if this queue is empty.

However, a better choice might be to use poll as it does the same thing except it return null instead of an exception when the queue is empty.

Comment: `poll()` is no replacement for what he wants since it only returns the head. Whereas `remove(Object o)` deletes the object no matter the position in the queue.

Comment: Assumption is the mother of all...    ;-)

Comment: Yes, I like your comment at the top. Its just as likely. esp as the Node doesn't extend Comparable.